# how to call the subclasses within the base_class?

Tags: python, oop, pytorch-geometric

I have problem and need some help towards object oriented
I want to create an graph dataset and some subclasses about modifying the base_graph dataset
my question how to call the subclasses within the base_class in order to remove/add nodes to the base_graph?

```
class base_graph(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, nodes, edges):
            ---
    def random_graph(self):
            # graph = generate random graph
    def __len__(self):
            ---
    def __repr__(self):
            ---
    def __getitem__(i):
            ---
            how to **call** Modifygraph_byAdding & Modifygraph_byDeleting here 
            # like randomOrder(Modifygraph_byAdding(graph), Modifygraph_byDeleting)



class Modifygraph_byAdding:
        def __init__(self, node):
            ---
        def add_sample_to_A(self, graph):
            ---



class Modifygraph_byDeleting:
        def __init__(self, node):
            ---
        def delete_node_from_A(self, node):
            ---
```

Comment: Ideally, nothing in the base class depends on any particular subclass.

Answer (score 1):

By "how to **call** `Modifygraph_byAdding` & `Modifygraph_byDeleting`" do you mean to pass instances of those classes, or using them in combination with a user-defined call operator that executes some action?

Either case, you will at least need to provide such instances, either as arguments to `__getitem__`, or by giving `base_graph` two new members consisting of these two instances.

That said, I believe your design can be improved by simply noticing that you really don't need two new classes to define what, to me, appears to be functions that act on a specific instance of a `base_graph`. You could simply do

```
class base_graph(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, nodes, edges):
        self.nodes = nodes
        self.edges = edges

    def add(self, node):
        # code to add node to self.nodes
   
    def delete(self, node):
        # code to delete node from self.nodes
    
    def random_graph(self):
            # graph = generate random graph
    
    def __len__(self):
            ---

    def __repr__(self):
            ---

    def __getitem__(self, node_i):
            ---
            # here you can use self.add(node_i) and self.delete(node_i)
```

By the way, are you constructing new `base_graph`s using `random_graph`? Depending on how simple this function is, you may just want to stick its implementation inside of the `__init__` function and delete `def random_graph`.

Comment: what if, I want to create an subgraph of the random graph and have the node addition/deletion methods modify the subgraph created in __getitem__ would this approach, you suggested still work?

Comment: Yes, itt will still work provided that the subgraph is an instance of `base_graph` (or a class inherited from it.)

Comment: but according to building a dataset in pytorch geometric there are specific functions to use so probably it's bettter to create other classes to delete/add?


https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notes/create_dataset.html

Comment: I answered your question in reference to the code you provided, not including external libraries not mentioned in your original question. If you are using classes/functions of a specific library, I recommend you to open a new question and attach the relevant information there.

Comment: if I'm having a callable class to add/delete node in __getitem__ how to have it with node_i? shouldn't I have self.node[node_i] or create self.graph and have self.graph[node_i]?